# Adding to sqlite database from two classes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I got this activity AddFood from who I can add objects to my database. 
When I open the activity from one class (The class wich afterwards shows the databasecontent in a listview) everything works fine.

But when I'm opening the AddFood activity from my main class, fill in the field and click add, it doesent show when im looking for it in the class showing the list view.

This is my AddFood class minus the imports.

```
package com.example.mappe3;

public class AddFood extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private HousekeepingDBHelper hkDBhelper;

private EditText itemFood, itemWeight, itemPrice, itemBrand, itemCategory;
private String setFood, setWeight, setPrice, setBrand, setCategory;
private Spinner catagorySpinner;
private Button addButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_food);
    hkDBhelper = new HousekeepingDBHelper(this);

    itemFood = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemFood);
    itemWeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemWeight);
    itemPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
    itemBrand = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemBrand);
    itemCategory = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemCategory);

    catagorySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.catagory_spinner);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.catagory_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    catagorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void addItem(){
    setFood = itemFood.getText().toString();
    setWeight = itemWeight.getText().toString();
    setPrice = itemPrice.getText().toString();
    setBrand = itemBrand.getText().toString();
    setCategory = catagorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


    if(setFood.length() != 0 && setWeight.length() != 0 && setPrice.length() != 0
            && setBrand.length() != 0 && setCategory.length() != 0){
        Intent newIntent = getIntent();
        newIntent.putExtra("tag_grocery_foodItem", setFood);
        newIntent.putExtra("tag_grocery_weight", setWeight);
        newIntent.putExtra("tag_grocery_price", setPrice);
        newIntent.putExtra("tag_grocery_brand", setBrand);
        newIntent.putExtra("tag_grocery_category", setCategory);

        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, newIntent);
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_food, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.addButton){
        addItem();
    }
}
}
```

And heres the class that shows the content, and where I can use Addfood class:

```
package com.example.mappe3;

public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {

private HousekeepingDBHelper hkDBhelper;
private HousekeepingCursorAdapter hkCursorA;
private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private ListView foodList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    hkDBhelper = new HousekeepingDBHelper(this);
    foodList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.food_data);

    runner();
}

public void runner(){
    new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            hkCursorA = new HousekeepingCursorAdapter(DatabaseActivity.this, hkDBhelper.listAll());
            foodList.setAdapter(hkCursorA);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

    if(reqCode == ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE && resCode == RESULT_OK){
        hkDBhelper.addItem(data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_foodItem"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_weight"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_price"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_brand"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_category"));
        hkCursorA.changeCursor(hkDBhelper.listAll());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.database, menu);
    return true;
}   

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.addItem:
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, AddFood.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;            
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

When I am done filling in the fields in my AddFood class it runs finish(); and goes to its previous activity (DatabaseActivity) where I can se the new object in the list.

Here is my MainActivity.java. This is where I get trouble.

```
package com.example.mappe3;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button databaseB;
private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.food_db_button);
    databaseB.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

//THIS IS WHAT I THOUGT WAS ENOUGH TO DO THE SAME THING IN THIS CLASS
    if (id == R.id.addItem) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, AddFood.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.food_db_button){
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, DatabaseActivity.class);
        this.startActivityForResult(startIntent, 1);
    }

}
}
```

After Im done adding in the AddFood class from MainActivity it goes back to MainActivity, wich is what I want. But then, when Im opening the DatabaseActivity to go look for it, its not there. I can still see all the items added from the other class, but not the one I just added.

Hope my explanation makes sense to anyone.

Can someone see what Im doing wrong?

Edit: onActivityResult() in MainActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

    if(reqCode == ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE && resCode == RESULT_OK){
        hkDBhelper.addItem(data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_foodItem"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_weight"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_price"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_brand"),
                            data.getExtras().getString("tag_grocery_category"));
        hkCursorA.changeCursor(hkDBhelper.listAll());
    }
}
```

The error log:

```
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521): Process: com.example.s188094_mappe3, PID: 28521
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.s188094_mappe3/.AddFood
(has extras) }} to activity {com.example.s188094_mappe3/com.example.s188094_mappe3.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3928)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3978)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
com.example.s188094_mappe3.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:40)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5535)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3924)
10-29 11:13:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(28521):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddFood` class you create an `Intent` and fill it with data and this `Intent` is then passed back to the Activity that started `AddFood`. If `AddFood` is started from `DatabaseActivity`, the returned `Intent` is used to add the item to the database in `onActivityResult()`.

However, if `AddFood` is started from `MainActivity`, nothing is done with the returned `Intent` because you've not implemented `onActivityResult()` in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Hmm. I understand. Very good explanation. Well, I tried adding the onActivityResult() to the MainActivity and now I got this error: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.s188094_mappe3/.AddFood (has extras) }} Any ideas?

Comment: There must be more in the log. Stacktrace would be helpful. Please post your implementation of `MainActivity.onActivityResult()` and the logcat error including stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Don't try to post this as a comment. just edit your question and add this information at the bottom

Comment: You have a null pointer exception in  `MainActivity.onActivityResult` at line 40. Which line is that?

Comment: I'm guessing that `hkDBhelper` in `MainActivity` is `null`. Did you remember to set that up before starting the `AddFood` activity?